# significance of max pooling in lstm for sentiment Analysis

Tags: neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, max-pooling

Can someone explain significance of max pooling layer after lstm layer in case of sentiment analysis?

How does it improves encoding of whole sentence in case of just considering output of final time step vs output of max pooling?